# Why is "unsigned" mapped to a 32 bits in MSVC C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, struct, unsigned

I have the following structure defined in MSVC++ 2008:

```
struct{
 Uint16  XDD;
 unsigned XDD_UI:8;
 unsigned XDD_CR:8;
}byte;
```

When doing sizeof on the above structure it shows that *unsigned* uses 32 bits to store the data.

- Why is that, does it has something to do with memory alignment ?
- And how could I force the compiler to use only 8 bits as defined without
  touching the struct definition ?

Comment: could you please post code on how you verify that `XDD` takes up 32 bits?

Comment: You can find some information specific to bit-field packing with Visual-C++ here: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/bit-field-packing-with-visual-c/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `unsigned`, that is short for `unsigned int`, which is 32 bits wide on Windows. That means that it has alignment of `4`. And since your struct is aligned, there are two bytes padding between `XDD` and `XDD_UI`, and two bytes padding at the end of the struct.

Your struct is laid out like this:

```
0-1  XDD
2-3  <padding>
4-4  XDD_UI
5-5  XDD_CR
6-7  <padding>
```

If you want the struct to be packed then you need to pack it. Use `#pragma pack` to achieve that. However, even if you do that, the compiler produces a struct with size 6. That's because the bitfields are packed into an `unsigned int` and so your two bitfields will always consume 4 bytes.

If you made sure that your bitfields were declared as being of a type whose size was no larger than 2 bytes, then your struct would be 4 bytes. And that would be true for an aligned struct. For instance, this struct has size 4.

```
struct s {
    unsigned short XDD;
    unsigned short XDD_UI:8;
    unsigned short XDD_CR:8;
};
```

However, it would be seem to me to be more sensible to declare your struct without bitfields:

```
struct s {
    Uint16 XDD;
    unsigned char XDD_UI;
    unsigned char XDD_CR;
};
```

You can declare that struct aligned and have the layout that you desire.

Comment: Are there any useful programs which can be guaranteed to work under any conforming implementation under the rules mandated by the C standard which would not be guaranteed to work if bitfields could be allocated any way the compiler sees fit?  I understand what the rules are, but I'm curious why a compiler isn't allowed to e.g. provide a means of packing four six-bit fields into a 3-byte structure if the hardware could handle it decently.

Answer (score 1):

```
And how could I force the compiler to use only 8 bits as defined without touching the struct definition
```

Use `#pragma`

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct{
 Uint16  XDD;
 unsigned XDD_UI:8;
 unsigned XDD_CR:8;
}byte;
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: Using `#pragma pack(1)` the size of the struct is still bigger than expected.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on compiler and machine  unsigned could be 64 bit too. Since previously processors were 32 bit so it became common norm to use 32 bit for an int. But we should not rely on int or unsigned to determine it range always.

A char or unsgined char is sure way to using 8 bits. But internally compiler may have made adjustments it to be used as 4 byte for processing.

Comment: No, a `char` is _at least_ 8 bits, just like `unsigned` is _at least_ 16 bits.

Comment: But sizeof char is always 1 in C lang

Comment: True, but `CHAR_BIT` isn't always 8.